# Oily Beer - Can I get the head back?

Tags: recipe-formulation

I'm refining a recipe for a chocolate wheat ale. I'm using 2 pounds of chocolate malt, which seems to be exceptionally oily, effectively killing the head. It still has carbonation, just no head.

Any ideas on neutralizing the oils? Or maybe sub the chocolate malt for something similar?

Comment: I take it you've made this before and you know that's the problem?  What's the rest of the recipe?  What yeast, pitching rate, and fermentation schedule are you using?  All of those can have a huge effect on head.

Comment: Well, the oils on the top of the beer is what gives it away.

Comment: OK, so you can see oils.  Do you know for certain it's from the chocolate malt?

Comment: The rest is liquid wheat extract, half pound of crystal, and a nottingham yeast. I'm 80% sure it's the choclate.

Comment: Hmmm, strange.  Like I said, I've never seen it even when I've used 2 lb. of chocolate malt in a recipe of mine.  Did you steep the chocolate malt?  How long and at what temp?  Not sure that matters, but we may discover something.

Comment: Steeped for ~30 minutes at boil.

Comment: You shouldn't steep at a higher temp than about 170F, especially with dark malts like that.  Whether or not it contributed to your problem is hard to say.  But if you boiled the chocolate malt, it could have a negative flavor impact.  I guess that maybe it could solubulize oils in the malt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 lb. of chocolate malt is really a lot!  Are you sure you want to do that?  IF the chocolate malt is making the beer "oily", then cutting it back would reduce that affect.  However, I've never found chocolate malt to do that, so maybe you have another issue.